# Product Images are uploading but not showing up after upload

Tags: product-images, image-upload

[image: I've checked in the folder and these are uploading fine but it stays stuck on "Complete"]

Image upload is not working, it stays stuck on "Complete" like this and nothing happens. My magento version is 1.9.1.0. I've changed the media folder permissions also checked removing the cache storage and magento cache, reindexed the data but nothing seems to work for me

Comment: Check your error logs

Comment: The logs its generating has nothing to do with the upload, the errors its showing in the log were there even when it was working before, I installed the SUPEE-8788 and then started facing all these errors.

Comment: hi @azazel995 r u getting any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the same problem today.. the file js/mage/adminhtml/product.js was overridden by another file and it had "before patch" content..

i had to comment the line

```
this.uploader.removeFile(item.id);
```

to get it working, try it

Comment: this solution is not working

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same problem today.. the file `js/mage/adminhtml/product.js` was overridden by another file and it had "before patch" content..

i had to comment the line

```
this.uploader.removeFile(item.id);
```

to get it working, try it

to me this attempt did not work

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same problem today, the file `js/mage/adminhtml/product.js` was overridden by another file and it had `before patch` content.

I had to comment the line

```
this.uploader.removeFile(item.id);
```

to get it working, try it

to me, this attempt did not work.